# Im having problems using stdin and NULL in eclipse

Tags: c, fgets

Here is my code that I am having issues with.  The goal of the program is to scan in a bunch of doubles and perform some simple statistical operations on them.  The line I am having the issue with is the `fgets()`. I have included the `stdio.h`, it's just not showing up in the code. My actual question is where are the `stdin` and `NULL` giving me issues when I though they were part of the language?  The exact error I am getting is that both Symbol `stdin` and `NULL` could not be resolved.

```
 /*
 * simpleStats.c
 *
 *  Created on: Sep 17, 2018
 *      Author: David Liotta
 */

#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 256

int main(){

    double n, max, min, sum, mean;
    char line[BUFSIZE];
    int numsRead = 0;
    int numOfItems = 1; 
    n = -1;
    max = n;
    min = n;
    sum = n;

    while(n != 0 && fgets(line, BUFSIZE, stdin ) != NULL){
        numsRead = sscanf(line, "%f", &n);
        if(numsRead == 1 && n != 0){
            numOfItems++;
            if(n > max)
                max = n;
            if(n < min)
                min = n;
            sum = sum + n;
        }
        if(numsRead == 0)
            printf("Bad input\n");
    }

    mean = sum / numOfItems;

    printf("# of items: %i", numOfItems);
    printf("\nSum: %f.3", sum);
    printf("\nMax: %f.3", max);
    printf("\nMin: %f.3", min);
    printf("\nMean: %f.3", mean);
}
```

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE and it's only function is to let you to write the code, and if configured - pass it to the compiler.

Comment: Now, what issues exactly?

Comment: I bet you get a compiler warning on this line: `umsRead = sscanf(line, "%f", &n);` since n is an double and you are telling sscanf that you want to treat it like a float

Comment: David, if someone asked you for help with this, wouldn't you want to know the 'issue" ?

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, my compiler keeps telling me that both Symbol 'stdin' and 'NULL' could not be resolved. My question is, is this code correct and my compiler is wrong? Or am i simply not understanding where and when to use stdin and NULL?

Comment: Also, I bet this printf format specifier doesn't do what you think it does: `printf("\nSum: %f.3", sum);`

Comment: Is it really the compiler who is complaining, or Eclipse code checker?

Comment: Aside: `n = -1; max = n;
    min = n;
    sum = n;` is strange.  I'd recommend `max = -HUGE_VAL;  min = HUGE_VAL;
    sum = 0.0;`.  and `int numOfItems = 1;` --> `int numOfItems = 0;`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( in `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu17` )  Note other compilers use different options to obtain the same results.  The posted code results in: `untitled.c:17:35: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]`  for the statement: `numsRead = sscanf(line, "%f", &n);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should compile.  I suspect something might be wrong with your development environment.

Since you're running Eclipse, I'm assuming that your compiler is GCC.  I may be wrong though.

Try to locate your compiler executable, and run the compilation by hand:

```
gcc -Wall -o simpleStats simpleStats.c
```

or, if you're on Windows:

```
gcc.exe -Wall -o simpleStats.exe simpleStats.c
```

You may have to specify the full path to `gcc.exe`, (depending on your environment, it might even be called something else;  you may be able to retrieve the full path from the console window in Eclipse).

Pay close attention to the output.  Copy/paste the full output *verbatim* in your original post if you can (do not rephrase the warnings / error messages).

I seldom use Eclipse, but with most IDEs you get to chose what kind of project you want to create.  Make sure you selected something like "console application", the error you're referring to (`stdin` not being *resolved*) may suggest a linker error.  Again, it's hard to tell without the exact GCC output.

A couple more things to check:

- make sure your compiler and its dependencies are properly installed,
- make sure that this compiler is targeted at Windows (or whatever OS you use), not at some exotic embedded platform,
- most development environments come with a bunch of sample projects, see if you can build one.

Comment: Thanks, this is actually what my problem was, eclipse wasn't compiling correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having ended up being the compiler not correctly reading the code.  I used a different compiler, and with some minor syntax changes, the code worked fine.